# Ocelot Failed to match Route configuration for upstream path

Tags: c#, .net-core, ocelot

Hello Now I am trying to use Ocelot gateway Normally I have one api in different server such as

```
https://server_domain.net/kpiDashboardApi
```

without gateway if I send request directly to  below link , it works

```
https://server_domain.net/kpiDashboardApi/Report/DocumentTypeCounts
```

I want to reach endpoint in this api from Ocelot in my local I use below configuration json

```
{
  "Routes": [
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/kpiDashboardApi/Report/DocumentTypeCounts",
      "DownstreamScheme": "https",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "https://server_domain.net/kpiDashboardApi",
          "Port": 443
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/Report/DocumentTypeCounts",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "Post" ]
    }
  ],
  "GlobalConfiguration": {
    "BaseUrl": "https://localhost:5001"
  }
}
```

when U send request to `https://localhost:5001/kpiDashboardApi/Report/DocumentTypeCounts`

it return 404 and as error return in console below

> warn:
> Ocelot.DownstreamRouteFinder.Middleware.DownstreamRouteFinderMiddleware[0]
> requestId: 0HMFMPNHV9VHO:00000001, previousRequestId: no previous request id, message: DownstreamRouteFinderMiddleware setting
> pipeline errors. IDownstreamRouteFinder returned Error Code:
> UnableToFindDownstreamRouteError Message: Failed to match Route
> configuration for upstream path:
> /kpiDashboardApi/Report/DocumentTypeCounts, verb: POST. warn:
> Ocelot.Responder.Middleware.ResponderMiddleware[0]
> requestId: 0HMFMPNHV9VHO:00000001, previousRequestId: no previous request id, message: Error Code:
> UnableToFindDownstreamRouteError Message: Failed to match Route
> configuration for upstream path:
> /kpiDashboardApi/Report/DocumentTypeCounts, verb: POST. errors found
> in ResponderMiddleware. Setting error response for request
> path:/kpiDashboardApi/Report/DocumentTypeCounts, request method: POST

I can't find the missing part . Where is my mistake?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm having exactly the same issue, did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

I think you mixed Downstream & Upstream up.
Try such config (note values for Host and UpstreamPathTemplate):

```
{
  "Routes": [
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/kpiDashboardApi/Report/DocumentTypeCounts",
      "DownstreamScheme": "https",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "https://server_domain.net",
          "Port": 443
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/kpiDashboardApi/Report/DocumentTypeCounts",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "Post" ]
    }
  ],
  "GlobalConfiguration": {
    "BaseUrl": "https://localhost:5001"
  }
}
```